# Image format in segmentation via neural networks

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, pytorch, image-segmentation, rawimage

I am doing segmentation via deep learning in pytorch. My dataset is a .raw/.mhd format ultrasound images. 
I want to input my dataset into the system via data loader.

I faced few important questions:

- **Does changing the format of the dataset to either .png or .jpg make the segmentation inaccurate?**(I think I lost some information in this way!)
- **Which format is less data lossy?**
- **How should I make a dumpy array if I don't convert the original image format, i.e., .raw/.mhd?**
- **How should I load this dataset?**

Answer (score 0):

Knowing nothing about `raw` and `mhd` formats, I can give partial answers.

Firstly, `jpg` is lossy and `png` is not. So, you're surely losing information in `jpg`. `png` is lossless for "normal" images - 1, 3 or 4 channel, with 8 bit precision in each (perhaps also 16 bits are also supported, don't quote me on that). I know nothing about ultrasound images, but if they use higher precision than that, even png will be lossy.

Secondly, I don't know what `mhd` is and what `raw` means in the context of ultrasound images. That being said, a simple google search reveals [some package](https://sites.google.com/site/pjmedphys/tutorials/medical-images-in-python) for reading the former to numpy.

Finally, to load the dataset, you can use the [`ImageFolder`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/datasets.html#imagefolder) class from `torchvision`. You need to write a custom function which loads an image given its path (for instance using the package mentioned above) and pass it to the `loader` keyword argument.